# How to save my icon into 192*192 resolution with out spoiling its shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, android

I need to make an icon for android phones which have 192*192 resolution.

**How to make it proportionate with out losing the shape?**

This is the shape I want to be made to 192*192. When ever I keep the background transparent and save it (Illustrator CC), it's taking the actual size of the image 146*190 instead of 192*192.

I need something similar to *whatsapp* icon, *dropbox* type without any square backside.

**My icon:**

[image]

Comment: Hello Divi and welcome. First of all, we can't simply imagine the shape that you have in order to answer. 192 by 192 as you can tell is a square but you can fit all kinds of shapes inside a square. Simply keep a transparent background. Anyway, you should edit your question to add more details and an image of the icon itself to get an accurate answer.

Comment: Can't you just change the size of the art board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always create a 192x192 px square and make it to 0% opacity, put it on the back and then export it. The export will still "see" the 192x192 px square on the back as part of the image, therefore it will keep the proportions.

Just so you get my point, here's how it would look with a black background square, right before turning the opacity to 0%.

[image]

Comment: I was preparing my answer but you added it first so I thought I would better edit your answer and add some extra text plus the image I made for my answer :) There would've been no point in adding two answers.

Comment: cheers for adding the image to my answer :) upvoted you

Comment: Don't mention it. Like I said, two answers would've been pointless.

Comment: Thats so simple and easy.  I am a newbie to graphic design. Appreciate your help, Thanks.

Comment: If you are saving it as a png, remember to make the background square transparent, without a stroke or fill. Otherwise you will get that black background along with it. Make it white for a jpg save.